# app.oauth.grant is not a function (oauth2-server)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authorization, oauth2-server

[image]

Whenever I run node oauth module I get error like

> app.oauth.grant is not a function

Comment: can you upload the codes as well to help us understand what you're talking about

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem yesterday.  I switched my dependencies to a lower version of the libraries and things worked.  What I ended up with:

```
"body-parser": "^1.15.2",
"express": "^4.14.0",
"oauth2-server": "^2.4.1",
"request": "^2.83.0"
```